# Where to place ng-app in Blade

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I've just started the process of learning Angular and I'm a bit stumped. Currently, I have a master blade template that I use site wide in my Laravel app. Here is the pertinent piece.

```
<body>    
    @include('navbar')      
    @yield('content')    
    @yield('content2')      
</body>
```

In order to use AngularJS, I have to place the tag `ng-app` in the body line. If I have several pages that use different pieces of AngularJS code, how can I change the tag?

I'm hoping that someone has an idea. Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have to use ng-app in body. Just use <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="yourapp">

Comment: Same issue exists. I'm using one master template for my entire site.

Comment: As @YagizOzturk stated you don't have to use ng-app in the body. Just put it on the html tag, a div inside any of your templates, etc. A simple search on angular docs will tell you so: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` can be placed anywhere, on any element.

So, if you have one app for `navbar`, simply add `ng-app="navbarApp"` to the top most element of your `navbar` template.

As an aside, I would recommend reconsidering using separate apps, and instead focus on one app with several controls for various portions of your application.  This way the body element is your `ng-app` element, and the top most element of your `navbar` template is simply a `ng-controller` element.

Then you set a `<div ng-view>` element under your `navbar` and you can either assign each of your content includes it's own controller and still load as a single page, or you simply load the page with only the `navbar` portion and dynamically load views into this portion by performing simple controller routing.

This simplifies the views structure on the server side since you no longer have to worry about creating layout templates for every potential combination of components.  Just create the components and let the front-end load the components where needed.

**Note:** This is assuming you are building an application that doesn't require SEO capabilities.